# How to show this point is a global asymptotically stable point?

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am working with the SIR model with vital dynamics:

\begin{align}
\frac{dS}{dt} &= \mu (K - S)- \beta SI \label{eq3}\\
\frac{dI}{dt} &= I(\beta S - \gamma -\mu) \label{eq4}
\end{align}

where I discarded the last ODE since it does not appear in the first two.
The region for this problem is $D={(S,I) : S>0, I \geq 0, S+I \leq K}$

I found that one equilibrium point is $(K,0)$ which is a local asymptotically stable point if $\frac{\beta K}{\gamma + \mu} < 1$. How can I show that is indeed a globally stable point?
I thought about using the lyapunov function $V(S,I) = S+I-K$ from which get $\dot{V} = \mu(K-S-I) - \gamma I$. But since $S+I\leq K $
then I cannot conclude that $\dot{V}<0$. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to choose another lyapunv function?

Thank you

Comment: Well, $V(S,I) = S+I$ doesn't even have a strict local minimum at $(K,0)$ to begin with, so it's not a Lyapunov function no matter what $\dot V$ is...

Comment: Also, it's not true that $(K,0)$ is stable for all values of the parameters! It makes a difference whether $(\gamma+\mu)/\beta$ is greater or less than $K$.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to add that condition.. I am quite new to this area of maths so I am not sure how to choose a Lyapunov function for this problem.

Comment: Even if I try to use $V(S,I) = S + I - K$ which has a local minimum at $(K,0)$ I still get the same answer as above

Comment: $V(S,I)=S+I-K$ also doesn't have a local minimum there! Lyapunov functions are typically chosen as a sum of squares or something similiar.

Comment: What could I choose then for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try another approach, namely that you rule out periodic orbits using the [Dulac–Bendixson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem) with $1/I$ as your Dulac function.

Comment: I will try thank you